# Metodo Insert e update não funciona no azure

Tags: mysql, web-service, asp, microsoft-azure, inserir

Boa tarde

Amigos estou iniciando em desenvolvimento asp net e fiz uma aplicação web form e coloquei no azure.
É uma aplicação simples de cadastro de cardapio que acessa um banco mysql criado pelo azure tambem. 
O que acontece é que no visual estudio ela funciona perfeitamente faz todas as operaçoes do crud. mas quando envia para o azure ele não salva as informaçoes no banco. somente exclui e consulta. não faz insert nem update. Alguem ja teve esse problema ?
segue o link da aplicação [http://cmbcenter.azurewebsites.net](http://cmbcenter.azurewebsites.net/)/

Comment: Se você está iniciando em asp net, por que não começa pelo asp net core  mvc 1.0  e usa o entity framework? particularmente não gosto de web forms

Comment: Boa dica do @Aesir, Webforms foi descontinuado e hj é totalmente desencorajado.

Comment: Você ja tentou roda a aplicação em debug na sua maquina, apontando para o banco do clearDB?

Comment: Alguém tem algum link de ajuda para fazer a aplicação rodar em debug?